# Why can't I apply "ON" with CROSS APPLY

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I want to use CROSS APPLY with the table valued function as it is recommended.

So, for a instance this works perfectly fine.

```
SELECT
  TBL1.pkId,
  TBL1.roleIS,
  TBL1.Name INTO #tmpTBL
FROM TBL1
 CROSS APPLY Convert(@keys, ',' ) AS ArrayTBL
 WHERE ArrayTBL.item = TBL1.pkId
```

BUT as soon as I try to apply "ON" keyword, it start showing Syntax error. why is it so as
it is also a type of inner join?

```
SELECT
  TBL1.pkId,
  TBL1.roleIS,
  TBL1.Name INTO #tmpTBL
FROM TBL1
 CROSS APPLY Convert(@keys, ',' ) AS ArrayTBL
 ON ArrayTBL.item = TBL1.pkId
```

I am trying to apply "ON" just because I have below query where I need to use CROSS APPLY.

```
 Select Tbl1.pkey, Tbl1.Name, Tbl2.EmployeeName
  from Tbl1 inner join Tbl2 on Tbl1.id= Tbl2.Id
  inner join Convert(@keys, ',') AS Array
   ON Tbl2.ItemId = Array.item
   inner join Tbl3 on tbl3.id = Array.item
   inner join #tmpTBL on  #tmpTBL.pkId = Tbl3.id
```

Comment: There is no `ON` in a `CROSS`. `ON` is only valid with `INNER` or `OUTER`.

Comment: I still don't understand why you want the `ON` clause? use the `WHERE` clause, they are logically the same. In general - `CROSS` join doesn't have `ON` , and it shouldn't, it makes a Cartesian join .

Comment: Because `cross apply` is a "cross join" - and a cross join has no join columns. Using the standard keywords makes it clearer: `cross apply` is the same as `cross join lateral` in standard SQL.

Comment: A `cross join/apply` joins, by definition, all records on the left-hand side with all records on the right-hand side. So an `on` clause wouldn't make sense.

Comment: @Ben - `ON` is perfectly valid with `OUTER` joins also.

Comment: But how I will be able to apply CROSS APPLY in last query?

Comment: That looks like an inner join job for me.

Comment: yes that is a inner join with a function. But i want to use CROSS APPLY there. is it possible? And doing inner join like above is alright?

Comment: Or change the function to a table valued function and join as you would to a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use ON in the CROSS APPLY like in INNER | LEFT | RIGHT | APPLY but there is some flexibility and you can use CROSS APPLY according to your requirement. Try the below queries with CROSS APPLY and you will get all different output:

```
CREATE TABLE #test(id INT, ename VARCHAR(20))
CREATE TABLE #testOne(id INT, test_id INT, pname VARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO #test VALUES 
(1, 'Test'),
(2, 'Test1'),
(3, 'Test2')

INSERT INTO #testOne VALUES 
(1, 1, 'Test3'),
(2, 1, 'Test4'),
(3, 2, 'Test5')

SELECT t.id, t.ename, p.pname
FROM #test t
CROSS APPLY(SELECT pname FROM #testOne) p

SELECT t.id, t.ename, p.pname
FROM #test t
CROSS APPLY(SELECT pname FROM #testOne p WHERE p.test_id = t.id) p

SELECT t.id, t.ename, p.pname
FROM #test t
CROSS APPLY(SELECT pname 
            FROM #testOne p
            INNER JOIN #test tt ON tt.id = p.test_id
            WHERE tt.id = 2) p

SELECT t.id, t.ename, p.pname
FROM #test t
CROSS APPLY(SELECT pname FROM #testOne) p
WHERE t.id = 2
```